# Java Jhipster Get one object Vs get list

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I want to print pdf document document to get list of doctors , I succeeded to get the list by :

```
  final List<Doctor> page = doctorRepository.findAll();
```

But to get one doctor how can i do it ?
I tried to do :

```
Doctor d = doctorRepository.findOne(1L);
```

But it dosen't work .

Comment: Do you have a doctor with id 1L?

Comment: i have methode findOne(id)

Comment: My question is in your database is there a record that has id/primary key as 1L.

Comment: yes , it is ok i solve it . thank you